# Can someone help fix my vimrc config?

Tags: linux, unix, vi, vim

```
set nohlsearch
set ai
set bg=dark
set showmatch
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=DarkGray
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~
set list
autocmd BufRead *.py set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
syntax on
set listchars=tab:>-
set listchars+=trail:.
set ignorecase
set smartcase
map <C-t><up> :tabr<cr>
map <C-t><down> :tabl<cr>
map <C-t><left> :tabp<cr>
map <C-t><right> :tabn<cr>
map <F1> <Esc>
imap <F1> <Esc>
set pastetoggle=<F5>
```

This is my vimrc. I want to fix it so that it doesn't show >---- >---- when other people tab. Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set list
```

is doing this. You can

```
:set nolist
```

if it is bothering you but I recommend keeping it for python files (you might be coding in python looking at that autocommand). ie. ... Learn to love it. create a mapping if it is a regular issue.

Also there is

```
:retab
```

to remove tabs if you have an expandtab setting.

Answer (score 2):

Remove these lines:

```
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~
set listchars=tab:>-
```

Comment: Probably `set list` too. Unless you want to show new lines as well.